# catch invalid time input

Tags: java, time

What I want to do in my code is if the user input invalid time like 25:00:00 my code should catch the error and prompt the user that he input a invalid time. My if else statement seems not working.

```
public void setTime(int h, int m, int s){

        hour = ((h>=0 && h<=24) ? h:0 );
        minute = ((m>=0 && m<=60)? m:0);
        second =((s>=0 && s<=60)? s:0);
    }


    public void toRegularTime(){
        if(hour > 24){
            System.out.println("invalid time");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Input a Valid Time!", "Invalid Time!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }else
            System.out.format("%02d:%02d:%02d %s", ((hour==0 || hour ==12) ? 12:hour%12),minute,second,(hour<12 || hour>23? "AM" : "PM"));






}
```

Comment: `setTime` will accept `24:60:60`, which I doubt is what you intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `setTime` method you are already applying that check
`hour = ((h>=0 && h<=24) ? h:0 );`
and resetting `hour` back to zero. So logic in `toRegularTime` method is redundant. 
if you are not sure how Java ternary operator works, check this link 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Java

Also it is not clear in which order you are calling these methods.

Hope this helps!!